Docker container is running but localhost not working
I have a python flask app inside a docker container where im trying to run on localhost. When i run the image to create a new container i set the Host port to 8000 . So it looks like 8000:5000
When i run the docker container i get in the terminal the following :
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
2024-05-10 09:43:06 Press CTRL+C to quit
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Restarting with stat
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Debugger is active!
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Debugger PIN: 132-936-545
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Serving Flask app 'app'
2024-05-10 09:43:06  * Debug mode: on

However when trying to access on browser i get This site cant be reached
Whats wrong?

Which address did you use when trying to access it in the browser?

http://localhost:8000

It might be that your browser uses https by default, you could try http://localhost:8000?

i tried this also. didnt worked:(

If the startup messages say Running on http://127.0.0.1 then the main container process is listening only on the container-private localhost interface, and won't be reachable from the host system or other contexts that think they're localhost.  The linked question discusses this further for Flask applications specifically, there are two standard setups to make a Flask app listen everywhere.

I think you are missing one thing.
In order to access Docker's port as localhost, "port forwarding" must be performed. In other words, you need to connect the port of the host machine and the port of the Docker container.
Therefore, you must perform port forwarding with the -p option when running the docker container.
This is an example of running a Docker container with port forwarding options.
# -d: background execution
# -p: Map port 80 of the host machine to port 5000 of the container.

$ docker container run -d -p 80:5000 [image_name]

When you run the above, you will be able to access your Flask app via http://localhost:80 (or http://localhost).
I hope it was helpful to you. Thank you :)

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunatelly didnt worked:(
